# When Scrolling recyclerview clip parent view,How can i resolve that issue

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I got that error when i am using cliptochild & clipToPadding my parent view is clipping how can I resolve that problem how to resolve that issue when i am using recyclerview.

*This is my style.xml*

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"> 
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:typeface">serif</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowAllowEnterTransitionOverlap">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowAllowReturnTransitionOverlap">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
        <item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>
        <item name="android:clipChildren">false</item>
        <item name="android:clipToPadding">false</item> 
    </style>
```

*This is my layout.xml*

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/fare_bg"
            >


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/fare_bg"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/address_bar_lin"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="5dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ub__fare_split_search_icon" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="2dp">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/placesEdittxt"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:textColor="@color/textAddressColor"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        android:typeface="monospace" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_clear"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ub__x_normal" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/fare_bg"   >


        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: try providing some padding below the recycler view

Comment: R u checked screen shot.

Comment: `"can I resolve that problem how to resolve that issue "` what problem? what issue?

Comment: I want to navigation bar transparent  ,when i scroll the recyclerview visible cell in navigation bar but not in parent view.

Answer (score 0):

Remove weight from recyclerview because the parent is Relative Layout and Try this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false">


    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```